# Terminal find, rename by deletion

Tags: terminal

Mac will append a ' 2' (note the space) to the end of a file/folder that is  a copy of another file/folder inside the same directory... I was wondering if anybody knows how to batch remove/rename this ' 2' from a directory of folders from Terminal.

Comment: How do you want to rename the files? Just remove the trailing " 2" or something else?

Comment: yes, I want to remove the trailing " 2"... for directories inside of a directory ie... Music/Tom Petty 2/ ... ( not files or the files within the renamed directory )

Answer (score 3):

Use `find` to locate files like this way:

```
find . -name "* 2" -exec rm -r "{}" \;
```

This command will search for files and folders from where your are `.` with name `"* 2"` and delete every result `-exec rm {}`.

If you want to rename directories:

```
find . -name "* 2" -type d -exec rename 's/ 2/-copy/g' {} \;
```

As other command, locate only folders with name `"*.2"` and rename it replacing `2` with `-copy`.

If you don't have `rename` installed, you can also use

```
find . -name "* 2" -type d -exec bash -c '[[ -x "${0/ 2/-copy}" ]] || mv "$0" "${0/ 2/-copy}"' {} \;
```

(The `[[ -x` part tests whether a file/folder already exists).

Comment: but, what if you are trying to rename ( not delete ) directories ( not files ).

Comment: I update my answer. It will delete both files and folders.

Comment: The OP wants to *rename* files/folders, not only delete them

Comment: @patrix read carefully: "how to batch remove/rename". This usually means one or another, isn't it?

Comment: see Ken's first comment to your answer :-)

Comment: the 'remove' part of my question referred to the ' 2' at the end of the dir name... not the entire directory ( or file ) it is more of a batch rename for directories ( not files within directories )

Comment: Ok, updated again.

Answer (score 0):

Well, just in case anybody else comes up with this same question... I found a simple resolution.... if you have Homebrew

```
brew install rename
```

...

```
rename -s " 2" '' *
```

turns Music/Tom Petty 2 into Music/Tom Petty. 
Likewise, if you wanted to add something to your directory names with a similar ending like ' 2', you could...

```
rename -s " 2" '-blob' *
```

... `Music/Tom Petty 2/`

becomes

```
Music/Tom Petty-blob/
```